# C# SQL Parameter Errors in Loops

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Please help me out with this. I have this small application to load txt files into a sql db and it works fine with sqlite. When I ported to SQL I started getting 'parameter already declared' errors.. If anyone can help me reorganize this code, it would be great! I need to get the parameter definitions outside of the loops or something..

```
using System; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.SQLite; 
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace JohnDeereCMMDataParser 
{ 
    internal class Program 
    {


        public static List<string> GetImportedFileList()
        {
            List<string> ImportedFiles = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(@"Server=FRXSQLDEV;Database=RX_CMMData;Integrated Security=YES"))
            {
                connect.Open();
                using (SqlCommand fmd = connect.CreateCommand())
                {

                    fmd.CommandText = @"SELECT FileName FROM Import;";
                    fmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlDataReader r = fmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        ImportedFiles.Add(Convert.ToString(r["FileName"]));

                    }
                }
            }
            return ImportedFiles;
        } 




        private static void Main(string[] args) 
        {




            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=FRXSQLDEV;Database=RX_CMMData;Integrated Security=YES"))
            {


                con.Open();

                using (SqlCommand insertCommand = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to SQL server...");
                    SqlCommand cmdd = con.CreateCommand();
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\js91162\Desktop\", "R.txt*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FeatType", DbType.String));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FeatName", DbType.String));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Value", DbType.String));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Actual", DbType.Decimal));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Nominal", DbType.Decimal));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Dev", DbType.Decimal));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TolMin", DbType.Decimal));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TolPlus", DbType.Decimal));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OutOfTol", DbType.Decimal));


                        List<string> ImportedFiles = GetImportedFileList();

                        foreach (string file in files.Except(ImportedFiles)) 


                        {

                            var FileNameExt1 = Path.GetFileName(file);

                            cmdd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileExt", FileNameExt1));
                            cmdd.CommandText =
                                @" 
                    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'RX_CMMData' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Import')) BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Import WHERE FileName = @FileExt; END";



                            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmdd.ExecuteScalar());
                            con.Close();
                            con.Open();

                            if (count == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Parsing CMM data for SQL database... Please wait.");


                                insertCommand.CommandText =
                                    @"
                    INSERT INTO Import  (FeatType, FeatName, Value, Actual, Nominal, Dev, TolMin, TolPlus, OutOfTol, PartNumber, CMMNumber, Date, FileName) 
                    VALUES     (@FeatType, @FeatName, @Value, @Actual, @Nominal, @Dev, @TolMin, @TolPlus, @OutOfTol, @PartNumber, @CMMNumber, @Date, @FileName);";






                                string FileNameExt = Path.GetFullPath(file);
                                string RNumber = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

                                string RNumberE = RNumber.Split('_')[0];

                                string RNumberD = RNumber.Split('_')[1];
                                string RNumberDate = RNumber.Split('_')[2];

                                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(RNumberDate, "yyyyMMdd", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
                                string cmmDate = dateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                                bool parse = false;

                                foreach (string tmpLine in lines)
                                {


                                    string line = tmpLine.Trim();
                                    if (!parse && line.StartsWith("Feat. Type,"))
                                    {
                                        parse = true;
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    if (!parse || string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }

                                    Console.WriteLine(tmpLine);
                                    foreach (SqlParameter parameter in insertCommand.Parameters)
                                    {
                                        parameter.Value = null;
                                    }

                                    string[] values = line.Split(new[] { ',' });

                                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        SqlParameter param = insertCommand.Parameters[i];
                                        if (param.DbType == DbType.Decimal)
                                        {
                                            decimal value;
                                            param.Value = decimal.TryParse(values[i], out value) ? value : 0;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            param.Value = values[i];
                                        }
                                    }



                                }

                                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PartNumber", RNumberE));
                                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CMMNumber", RNumberD));
                                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", cmmDate));
                                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileName", FileNameExt));
                                // 

                                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            }

                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("CMM data successfully imported to SQL database...");

                    }
                    con.Close();

            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

FYI - the PartNumber, CMMNumber, Date, etc at the bottom are pulled from the file name and I need it in the table next to each respective record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your Command objects, you need to do a

```
insertCommand.Parameters.Clear();
```

before you do any

```
insertCommand.Parameters.Add();
```

calls. The parameters are keyed when you add them to the collection, so when you reuse the same command object and add a new set of parameters the keys are colliding. Or you could just create a new Command object for each call, whichever suits you best.

Comment: When i do insertCommand.Parameters.Clear(), the code runs but only the first line from each txt document is added to the db.. ???

Comment: @jake, that sounds like you have a problem with your looping, which you didn't notice before because your code was erroring at the start of the second iteration. The Parameters.Clear() is not causing your code to fail, unless you have put it in the wrong spot. Run the code under the debugger, and start inspecting the code flow and the values of local variables, and look for reasons why a loop could end early.

Comment: The code no longer fails, it just doesn't go through all lines of each file as it should anymore. (it did with sqlite), now it completes but when i check the db, it has only added the part number and data from the first line of each file... weird deal...make sense?

Comment: @jake - i just put your code into VS to make it easier to read, and the first thing i notice is that your one and only *insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();* is **outside** of the foreach loop that iterates through the lines of the file you are processing - this means you will insert only one line per file.

Comment: Mannnn...  Makes sense.... Ok. I will give that a shot in the morning! thanks for the tips!